# System.IO.Pipes on Windows 2000

Tags: windows, .net-3.5, pipe, windows-server-2000

Is there any way to get .NET 3.5 working on Windows 2000? Specifically, the only part I need is the System.Core.dll to use the System.IO.Pipes namespace.

Hackish workaround methods are fine, if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Workaround found - I started pulling the code out of System.Core.dll using Red Gate's .NET Reflector and adapting it to my project, but halfway through found that someone has already done the same thing here http://hall.org.ua:800/syberia1/browser/Syberia2/src/Syberia2/Microsoft/IO/Pipes so used that instead.